# How to output multiple variables using Azure Kusto?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm fairly new to Azure Kusto query-language. I'm trying to output 2 variables. This has to be something very simple, I just don't know how. I have tried using datatable, make-series, print, etc. functions to no avail. Here's my current code:

```
let allrequests = requests | project itemCount, resultCode, success, timestamp | where timestamp > now(-1h) and timestamp < now(-5m);

let requestcount = allrequests | summarize sum(itemCount);

let errorcount = allrequests | where toint(resultCode) >= 400 and toint(resultCode) <= 499 | summarize sum(itemCount);

requestcount; errorcount
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `union` is one way, but if you want them on a single row use the `print` statement ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/printoperator)):

```
let requestcount = requests
 | summarize sum(itemCount);
let errorcount = exceptions
 | summarize count();
print requests = toscalar(requestcount), exceptions = toscalar(errorcount)
```

Comment: This is actually way better, since union doesn't always return the result in the same order as print does. There is a sort-function, but that is not optimal. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You can join results using the [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/unionoperator) operator.

```
let allrequests = requests | project itemCount, resultCode, success, timestamp | where timestamp > now(-1h) and timestamp < now(-5m);

let requestcount = allrequests | summarize sum(itemCount);

let errorcount = allrequests | where toint(resultCode) >= 400 and toint(resultCode) <= 499 | summarize sum(itemCount);

errorcount | union requestcount
```